# file read inside class of project A and calling this class in project B

Tags: java, eclipse, file, filepath

I have 2 projects. Project A and Project B.

Inside Project A i have a class MyClass that has a method say: readMyFile() which reads a file from some xyz path.

Now I am trying to call readMyFile() from a class in Project B. And I get the error stating the file being attempted to be read does not exist.

How can I make sure that the file that is being read by readFile() in MyClass in Project A, is also visible in Project B ?

Comment: Create a jar of the ProjectB and add as a external jar to ProjectA. Or better use `maven` for dependency management.

Comment: Don't read jar resources a a `File`. That's probably your first problem, if that's what you are doing. Read it as a resource with `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` or one of it's variants. Second, I wouldn't try to read files directly from A using paths dependent on jar B. Instead just create a class in project B that will serve up its resources. And just call that class/method from project A

Answer (score 0):

**Comment to expanded answer:**

> Don't read jar resources a a `File`. That's probably your first problem, if that's what you are doing. Read it as a resource (via URL) with `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` or one of it's variants. Second, I wouldn't try to read files directly from A using paths dependent on jar B. Instead just create a class in project B that will serve up its resources. And just call that class/method from project A

For example

```
ProjectB
       src
          resources
                 images
                      background.png
                 text
                      stackoverflow.txt
          mypackage
                 ResourceFinder.java
```

ResourceFinder.java

```
public class ResourceFinder {
    public static final String BACKGROUND_IMG = "background.png";
    public static final Sting STACKOVERFLOW_TXT = "stackoverflow.txt";

    // maybe you'll want to do some try/catching null checks
    // I'm being lazy
    public static BufferedImage getImage(String fileName ) throws Exception {
        URL url = ResourceFinder.class.getResource("/images/" + fileName);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
        return image;
    }

    public static InputStream getTextFile(String file) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = ResourceFinder.class.getResourceAsStream(
                                                        "/text/" + fileName);
        return is;
    }
}
```

Then in your Project A, you could just do something like

```
BufferedImage image = ResourceFinder.getImage(ResourceFinder.BACKROUND_IMG);

or

InputStream is = ResourceFinder.getTextFile(ResourceFinder.STACKOVERFLOW_TXT);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Keep in mind that when you use `File` or any of its `FileXxx` variants, you are reading from the file system. So any hard coded path you use may not work, once the file is "jarred", because the location is no longer the same. Thats why we read it via an URL, either with `Class.getResource()` which returns a `URL` or `Class.getResourceAsStream()` which returns an `InputStream`, using an URL under the hood. There are other variants using `ClassLoader` also. See the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) Apis for other variants.